# Type promotion Java

Tags: java, casting

I`m learning Java with the Herbert Schildt book's: Java a Beginner's Guide.
In that book appears this code:

```
// A promotion surprise!
class PromDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        byte b;
        int i;
        b = 10;
        i = b * b;      // OK, no cast needed

        b = 10;
        b = (byte) (b * b);     // cast needed!!

        System.out.println("i and b: " + i + " " + b);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I must use (byte) in the line:

```
b = (byte) (b * b);     // cast needed!!
```

b was defined as a byte and the result of b * b is 100 which is right value for a byte (-128...127).

Thank you.

Comment: In your case it is OK, but what if result would be out of `byte` range? Remember that compiler can't assume values of non-final variables.

Comment: @Pshemo why then does multiplying two `int`s not require a cast?

Comment: @RishavKundu I can't find any resource now but I am guessing that since most of the time programmers are dealing with ***small*** `int`s compiler assumes that risk of overflow is minimal, but even if it occurs programmers are aware of it so there is no point in reminding them about it. Anyway compiler **needs** to stop informing programmer about possibility of overflow somewhere. Lets say that `int*int` generates `long`. Compiler will need to inform us about possible lost of precision. But what should it do in case of `long*long`? (there needs to be some place where it assumes that *we know*).

Comment: You'll be more surprised by `b=b+1;` :)

Comment: avoid `byte` if you can. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892444/are-there-any-real-life-uses-for-the-java-byte-primitive-type/6895113#6895113

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JLS ([5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) gives rules about combining numeric types with a binary operator, such as the multiplication operator (`*`):

> - If either of the operands is of type double, the other one will be converted to a double.
> - Otherwise, if either of the operands is of type float, the other one will be converted to a float.
> - Otherwise, if either of the operands is of type long, the other one will be converted to a long.
> - *Otherwise, both operands will be converted to an int.*

The last point applies to your situation, the bytes are converted to ints and then multiplied.

Comment: it doesn't matter that i declared b as a byte. It will be converted to int due to *.
is it correct?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - since the first 3 conditions listed above have not been met, the last case applies of converting the byte operands to integers.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, byte and short will always be promoted to int, when you have a calculation like this:

```
byte b = 10;
b = (byte) (b * b);
```

So you actually multiply an integer with an integer, which will return an integer. Since you cannot assign an integer to a byte, you need the cast.

This is called "automatic type promotion" if you would like to Google it (to find e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

Comment: [This would be a better reference.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

Comment: Thank you, it is of course! Quote from 5.6.2 point 2: "Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int." - which applies to byte and char. Thanks for your hint :)

Comment: Sure.  I encourage you to add it to your answer as opposed to whatever other reference you've Googled.  JLS references are *always* more concrete.

Comment: I don' t understand why I am multiplying an integer with an integer.

Comment: @Euriloco:  Follow the link to the language specification.  It's a fall-back case.